# Creating multiindex for panda dataframe for x and y coordinate and timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm stuck with my knowledge of creating a multiindex for a pandas dataframe.
My dataframe is an image with 230 x 640. I have added a column with the timestamp and now I want to create a Multiindex with my x and y coordinate and timestamp. I need the timestamp also as index because I concat multiple frames with different timestamp but with same frame width and height.

Is there a way to create such an index? My objective is to get: Hey value on 2 and 0 is too high.

[Image of dataframe without index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1uAr.png)

My dataframe looks like (val is a temperature value):

```
 0    1   2  ..  639  ts

0    val val val ..  val
1    val ..
2    ..
..
229
```

Comment: what is the multiindex supposed to look like? [ts, x] or [ts, x, y] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want.

I'm assuming your "x" is in your rows and your "y" is in your columns and that you want a MultiIndex with ["ts", "x", "y"]:

```
(df
 .rename_axis('x').reset_index()
 .set_index(['ts', 'x'])
 .rename_axis('y', axis=1).stack()
 .rename('value')
)
```

Breaking it down:

- `rename_axis('x').reset_index()`: Rename the current index as "x" and turn it into a regular column (which will be needed for the next step.)
- `set_index(['ts', 'x'])`: Set the index to be a MultiIndex with ["ts", "x"]. This is pretty similar to the original DataFrame, only with "ts" moved to an index.
- `rename_axis('y', axis=1)`: Name the column axis as "y".
- `stack()`: Turn the columns into rows, adding the third component to the MultiIndex. The resulting Series should have the shape you wanted.
- `rename('value')`: Rename the Series as "value", in case you turn it back into a DataFrame with `to_frame()` that will be its name as a column.